# How to update a flag for all rows except the last 5 with the latest dates?

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

I have a DB2 LUW 9.7 table that looks something like this (before update):

```
Id     SubId     Name     New_Flag      Dttm
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  1        2      Sam            0      5/31/2017 1:30:00.000000 PM
  2        3      Joe            1      4/25/2018 12:30:00.000000 PM
  3        4      Ann            1      4/3/2018 2:10:00.000000 PM
  4        5      Tim            1      4/3/2018 2:15:00.000000 PM
  5        6      Tom            0      3/6/2017 2:00:00.000000 PM
  6        7      Art            1      4/3/2018 2:15:00.000000 PM
  7        8      Jen            1      4/25/2018 12:30:00.000000 PM
  8        9      Jim            1      4/3/2018 2:10:00.000000 PM
  ....many more records where New_Flag = 0
```

So, I update the New_Flag column to equal 1 for ID #1 and #5 and set the timestamp column, Dttm, to 8/3/2018 8:30:00.000000 AM. Now the table looks like this:

```
Id     SubId     Name     New_Flag      Dttm
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  1        2      Sam            1      8/3/2018 8:30:00.000000 AM
  2        3      Joe            1      4/25/2018 12:30:00.000000 PM
  3        4      Ann            1      4/3/2018 2:10:00.000000 PM
  4        5      Tim            1      4/3/2018 2:15:00.000000 PM
  5        6      Tom            1      8/3/2018 8:30:00.000000 AM
  6        7      Art            1      4/3/2018 2:15:00.000000 PM
  7        8      Jen            1      4/25/2018 12:30:00.000000 PM
  8        9      Jim            1      4/3/2018 2:10:00.000000 PM
  ....many more records where New_Flag = 0
```

I want to write an update query that will set the New_Flag column equal to 0 for all columns in the table except for the 5 with the most recent dates: ID #1, #5, #2, #7, and either #4 or #6. It doesn't matter if #4 or #6 is selected as the 5th record, so long as only 5 records are returned.

This is what the table should end up looking like (I arbitrarily chose ID #6 as one of the records that has New_Flag set to 0):

```
Id     SubId     Name     New_Flag      Dttm
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  1        2      Sam            1      8/3/2018 8:30:00.000000 AM
  2        3      Joe            1      4/25/2018 12:30:00.000000 PM
  3        4      Ann            0      4/3/2018 2:10:00.000000 PM
  4        5      Tim            1      4/3/2018 2:15:00.000000 PM
  5        6      Tom            1      8/3/2018 8:30:00.000000 AM
  6        7      Art            0      4/3/2018 2:15:00.000000 PM
  7        8      Jen            1      4/25/2018 12:30:00.000000 PM
  8        9      Jim            0      4/3/2018 2:10:00.000000 PM
  ....many more records where New_Flag = 0
```

I wrote the following that gets the 5 records, but I'm having trouble converting it to an UPDATE query that will set the New_Flag column equal to 0 for every row except these 5 records:

```
select distinct
    name,
    older
from
    (
        select
            t1.name,
            t1.dttm as older
        from
            myTable t1
            left outer join
            myTable y1 on
                y1.new_flag = t1.new_flag
                and y1.dttm < t1.dttm
        where
            t1.new_flag = 1
        order by
            2 desc
    )
fetch first 5 rows only
;
```

Is it possible to do this in an UPDATE query (preferably not in a stored procedure)? Is there a more efficient way to achieve what I'm trying to accomplish?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Gordon's answer wasn't quite on the mark, he did help set me on the right path.

Here's the solution I came up with:

```
update myTable t1
set new_flag = 0
where not exists (
    select 
        1
    from
        (
            select
                st2.*,
                row_number() over (order by st2.dttm desc) as seqnum
            from
                myTable st2
            where
                new_flag = 1
        ) t2
    where
        seqnum <= 5
        and t1.name = t2.name
);
```

This should ensure that if a record has a New_Flag = 0 and a Dttm that is more recent than one of the top 5 most recent records, that it will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with `fetch`/`offset`:

```
update mytable
   set flag = 0
   where dttm < (select t2.dttm
                  from mytable t2
                  order by t2.dttm desc
                  offset 4 fetch first 1 row only
                 );
```

EDIT:

If the above doesn't work in your version, perhaps this does:

```
update mytable
   set flag = 0
   where dttm < (select t2.dttm
                  from (select t2.*, row_number() over (order by t2.dttm desc) as seqnum
                        from mytable t2
                       ) t2
                  where seqnum = 5
                 );
```

Comment: Unfortunately, offset does not appear to be enabled on the system I'm using.

Comment: Do you mean `limit 4 fetch first 1 row only`?

Comment: It looks like `limit` and `offset` are both enabled/disabled by the same configuration property, so it doesn't work with that one either.

Comment: So, your edit sets the flag equal to 0 for the 4 most recent records where flag = 1, whereas I was trying to get all records except for the 5 most recent. However, I think can use this to get the answer now. Thanks!

Comment: @user2063351 . . . I think I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will work on recent versions of Db2 LUW, and is arguably the neatest way to achieve what you want

```
update 
(   select
        new_flag 
    from 
    (   select 
            new_flag
        ,   row_number() over (order by dttm desc) as seqnum
        from
            myTable t
    )
    where
        seqnum <= 5
    and new_flag <> 0
)
set new_flag = 0
```